# How to remove the active black border on noUiSlider

Tags: javascript, nouislider

When selecting and dragging a handle on noUiSlider there is a black border that appears.

I cannot find the css to stop/alter this. I think some css is being injected, but I have no idea what.

I have looked at

```
.noUi-active {
  display:none;
  /*border: 5px solid red;*/
}
```

the display:none works, but nothing else touches the black border.

Thanks.

Comment: All we can do is guess without seeing this, you need to make [mre], or at least find a example of this in https://refreshless.com/nouislider/examples/ so we can exam the code. Also did you try putting `!important` to override border style, if you are sure that is the class: `.noUi-active {
  border: 0 !important;
}`

Comment: Hi, it's the out of the box behaviour on the simplest implementation :)  Thanks for the suggestions. However, I've moved on now to using jqueryUi and jQueryUi-slider-pips. There comes a time when you just have to leave it :).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not using this anymore, but looking at some css from jquery-ui-slider-pips which provides some scales (pips) for jquery-ui.slider I noticed a comment about getting rid of the "godawful outline" :) and say the use of:

```
outline: none;
```

I commented it out and yes the "godawful" outline appeared, so I figure this might help someone else.

:)